# Can not connect to mysql through python

Tags: python, mysql, authorization, mysql-connector-python

I am using the mysql-connector library in python running on Linux Mint 19.3.

I am trying to connect using the root user in the following code.

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(user=username, password=password, host='localhost')
```

For debugging I have temporarily hardcoded in my username (which is the root user) and my password. I get the following error...

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'myUsername'@'localhost'
```

From the terminal I can run 'sudo mysql' and have total access at the mysql prompt.

Comment: When you run sudo mysql are you using the same username and password as described on your db connector.connect object?

Comment: Yes I am using the same user and password. My linux username and password.